# Flow - A type that can only result from a function

Tags: typescript, types, flowtype

Using Flow (or typescript out of curiosity), can I create a type that can only result from a specific function? I want to be able to type a string that has been sanitized as something like "SanitizedString". However, if I simply aliased `type SanitizedString = string`, then I could assign a non-sanitized string to that type.

So instead, I want to type it so it can only come from a return from my `sanitizeHtml()` function. Does anyone know if this is possible in either type system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Typescript, you could do it with intersection types and a "tagging" interface.

```
interface Sanitized {
    isSanitized: never;
}

type SanitizedType<T> = T & Sanitized;

function sanitizeString(str: string): SanitizedType<string> {
    return str as SanitizedType<string>;
}

function printSanitizedString(sstr: SanitizedType<string>): void {
    console.log(sstr);
}

printSanitizedString("Hello, world!"); // ERR
printSanitizedString(sanitizeString("Hello, world!")); // OK
```

As we don't actually need the value of `isSanitized` for anything (we just want it for the typing), we type it is as `never` so we get errors if we try to use it. Being an intersection type, the return value of sanitizeString(str) is usable wherever a normal string is usable.

Comment: This seems a little hacky and not transparent of intent but it gets the job done perfectly. Awesome work!

Comment: Yeah. In actual code you should probably instead have a wrapped object that your sanitize function returns, such as `type SanitizedString = { value: string }`. It means you have to unwrap it when you use it, but it expresses the intent much better.